# CSS Arrange Button elements (HTML)

Tags: html, css, button

I have my CSS and html form in this link. http://jsfiddle.net/qLgCX/1/  How can I make the "Update" and "reset" button in same row in the below output?
I am using the same CSS for few other html which contain only 1 submit button. I am afraid that changing the css will effect them as well. [image]

[image]

```
#stylized button{
clear:both;
margin-left:150px;
width:125px;
height:31px;
background:#666666 url(img/button.png) no-repeat;
text-align:center;
line-height:31px;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-size:11px;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: You should wrap each of your lines in a paragraph and not use `<br>`. Then you can add a class `.contains-btn` to the last one and easily `text-align: center` its content. And inside it use inline-block for each button. Whether there is one or two of them won't change their centering (if this is the desired style) EDIT: I won't provide a fiddle because the site won't let me copy by keyboard or mouse the HTML code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/qLgCX/10/

This solution will not effect your other forms as you have requested.  It does require some modification of the HTML however, that being, adding a class to the buttons.

**The HTML I modified:**

```
<button type="submit" class="custom-submit" >Update</button>
<button type="reset" class="custom-reset">Reset</button>
```

**The CSS I added:**

```
#stylized button.custom-submit, #stylized button.custom-reset {
    float: left;
    clear: none;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Or if you wanted to do it more efficiently, you only need one class:

```
<button type="submit" class="UpdateReset" >Update</button>
<button type="reset" class="UpdateReset">Reset</button>
```

And you can apply that CSS only once, without any parents in the selector:

```
.UpdateReset {
    float: left;
    clear: none;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: wow, using the tag name in class selectors, declaring the same CSS twice, and making use of `float`. i don't care that you didn't choose my answer, i'm concerned that these kind of inefficient and archaic coding habits are being provided as answers at all. we can't just provide answers that work, we need to provide good answers, and teach people how to code the right way.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea - Float is a perfectly reasonable method of of getting this done.  He also needed to complete the request without breaking his other forms which have only one button, in which case your solution breaks.  It fails to center the buttons in the case that there is only 1 button and not two.  Hence the specific style rules to address his very specific issue.  Considering he has several other forms which have only 1 button and this is the only one that has two, the above is a perfectly reasonable solution, and if he so chooses he can combine the selectors.

Comment: And quite frankly the above is a FAR better solution than the other two answers below. (excluding yours).

Comment: it falls in line with the general idea that there are many roads to the same destination. from an execution standpoint, everything you did here will work. but 'it works' is the coding worlds version of 'good enough', and we should be teaching 'best'. why do you need two classes here? why do you need to declare the same CSS twice? Why qualify your class CSS with an ID parent? The answer to all these is you don't, unless you are actively trying to make it less efficient.

Comment: The answer to the first bit is yes, the css can be combined, i'll even edit the above to take that into account.  As for the classes, as I specifically described already.  The OP has other HTML forms in which if modified for the above, will break the others.  The situation requires specificity to those two individual fields, and so I tailored the CSS to follow that requirement.

Comment: whatever, im not tricking to bicker. keep coding like a wordpress developer, have fun with it.

Comment: without even fixing the terrible HTML, a proper class implementation of CSS => http://jsfiddle.net/qLgCX/12/

Comment: Proper yes, I don't deny this.  It will however break the rest of his forms unless he implements the same.  Based on how this particular form is stylized around an ID in the first place, it is perfectly reasonable to assume that there are potentially many other forms that are styled differently based off a separate ID also.  Either way both are specific cases based on what is provided to me.  I can suggest to the OP to rewrite his sites code all day long to be more "proper", but at the end of the day its up to them to make that change, and if they do they are smart enough to adapt all code.

Comment: agreed, no question there. that was my point though, and i admit i made the same mistake with my answer: just dismissing bad code as "if they are smart they'll fix it" produces bad code. i see crazy stuff, people using the same ID for all forms, jQuery solutions to a CSS problem ... it is our duty to teach and improve when we see these things, not just fix and move on.  thats it though, promise ill step off my soapbox now.

Comment: hahaha no problems m8, the jquery solution to a css problem is my fav for sure

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I swear by `inline-block`. I had to modify the `margin-left` as well, and remove the `<br>`s that you used. Here is the updated version:

http://jsfiddle.net/qLgCX/3/

I could spend a week optimizing it the rest (there are far easier and more extensible ways to do what you did), but this should fix your specific issue without intruding much on your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

you can try display:inline-block in the css for the buttons. 
if you do not intend to do it on all buttons (i.e.) if you want buttons only on this particu;ar page to be horizontally aligned, then give an id to the div containing the buttons and then define css as

```
#divid #stylizedbtn{
display:inline-block;
}
```

sorry, i did not see the fiddle at first.

please try this:
1.remove the 
 tags after the first button

```
<button style="display:inline-block" type="submit">Update</button>
<button style="display:inline-block" type="reset">Reset</button><br><br>
```

change your css for

```
#stylized button{
margin-left:50px; //some lesser value than 150px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a new style class:

```
.mybutton { margin-left:20px !important;}
```

and apply it to your buttons

[see my Fiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/qLgCX/11/)

```
<button type="submit" class="mybutton">Update</button> 
<button type="reset" class="mybutton">Reset</button><br><br>
```

(I also removed the line break tags as well after submit)

Comment: This does not put the buttons on the same line.

Comment: Sorry, my saved "jsFiddle" didn't have the class="mybutton" applied to Reset.  If you add that piece into the code it should work. (http://jsfiddle.net/qLgCX/14/)